# nexus-ant-tasks - change the description of a staging upload

Tags: java, ant, nexus

Our build procedure uses ANT to do everything and I'm now required to use a Nexus Stage/Promote model.

In order to do this I'm using nexus-ant-tasks:

https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-ant-tasks

I noticed that when uploading the description of the upload is always ""Started by nexus-staging-ant-tasks"

Having a brief look in the code of the nexus-ant-tasks it doesn't look as though I can change this anywhere, however I'm putting this out therein case I'm wrong.

Is there any way I can change the description of the upload?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fully working example that uses Ant with Apache Ivy and another one with Eclipse Aether in the [nexus-book-examples project](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples).

And there is also a [free video series I recorded](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/members-only/video-gallery-2/free-training-sonatype-nexus-and-clm-tips-from-the-trenches/) about training that includes episodes about Ant.

Comment: Hi Manfred. I'm not sure how that answers my specific question. The setup of the nexus staging properties in your example give no indication of changing the description of the staging upload task. I am not using Ivy - we have an inherited hodgepodge of maven dependency management combined with ANT build tasks (which I have no want to change). Let me be clear - I'm not concerned with the description of the ANT task, it's the desc shown in the Nexus web UI of the staging entry that I want control over. Unless, I'm missing something Ivy specific that I don't know about that will change that.